Is a conditioned gaussian distribution sub-gaussian?
I am thinking that if $X_n$ converges to a gaussian distribution $N(0,1)$, whether $X_n|A_n$ converges to a sub-gaussian distribution, where $A_n$ is an event about $X_n$. Because we can show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n>t|A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P(\{X_n>t\} \cap A_n)}{P(A_n)}=\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}P(\{X_n>t\} \cap A_n)}{\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)}
$$
If $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)=P(A)>0$, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n>t|A_n)=\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}P(\{X_n>t\} \cap A_n)}{\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)}\le\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n>t)}{P(A)}
$$
Since we assume $X_n$ converges to $N(0,1)$ in distribution, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n>t|A_n)\le C\cdot P(Z>t)
$$
where $Z~N(0,1)$. So this is exactly one of the definitions of sub-gaussian distribution, so can we say that $X_n|A_n$ weakly converges to a sub-gaussian distribution in this case?
It seems a little bit strange because I make the upper bound "too large" by using $P(\{X_n>t\} \cap A_n)\le P(X_n>t)$, but it seems it is still a sub-gaussian.

What are you assuming about the events $A_n$? How are they defined and is their limit well-defined?

$A_n$ is a set regarding to random variable $X_n$, for example, $A_n={\omega:X_n(\omega)\in B}$, so I can define $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n)$.
